# How to find address from the Census Blocks Code?

Tags: usa, geospatial, us-census, geocoding, address

I have Census Blocks Code data (15 digits code) and need to get corresponding street names and addresses in NYC. What is the best source of such information?

Comment: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/geocoder.html ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's possible to get block code if you know its address with this geocoder but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a few lines of R, taking the spatial over of the roads file and the block file, then iterating through the list and dumping it to a nice table. I'm not sure of any other way to do this.

Comment: I saw somewhere that Tiger/Lines files for edges should be used to get addresses. Is it also correct? Could you please advise some link to the file with road information?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html

Comment: Yes. But I'm a bit confused because this link https://www.e-education.psu.edu/natureofgeoinfo/c4_p8.html
 indicates that the Tiger files with edges should be used (see  https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/EDGES/) instead of road data. Also there is info at https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2016-series-information-for-the-address-range-feature-name-county-based-re stating that AddrFeat Tiger files are even better. Both type of files have necessary fields to create Address Locator.  
So may be you can advise which file should be used: road, edges or addrfeat?

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with human-readable, you can find the block maps at https://www2.census.gov/geo/maps/dc10map/GUBlock/st36_ny/place/p3651000_new_york/.

Comment: I just found there some maps in pdf files but there are no texts with addresses there.

Comment: who is not fine with human-readable? bots?